# how i can connect and login in mysql localhost in php by using this html code

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

how i can connect with database by using this code and how i can login for student and redirect to the student panel please write down
the php login code

```css
body {
 background: #DCDDDF url(http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/7/7AF2Qzt.png);
 color: #000;
 font: 14px Arial;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}
h1{ font-size:28px;}
h2{ font-size:26px;}
h3{ font-size:18px;}
h4{ font-size:16px;}
h5{ font-size:14px;}
h6{ font-size:12px;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{ color:#563D64;}
small{ font-size:10px;}
b, strong{ font-weight:bold;}
a{ text-decoration: none; }
a:hover{ text-decoration: underline; }
.left { float:left; }
.right { float:right; }
.alignleft { float: left; margin-right: 15px; }
.alignright { float: right; margin-left: 15px; }
.clearfix:after,
form:after {
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.container { margin: 25px auto; position: relative; width: 900px; }
#content {
 background: #f9f9f9;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%, rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f8f8f8', endColorstr='#f9f9f9',GradientType=0 );
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
 -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
 -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
 border: 1px solid #c4c6ca;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 25px 0 0;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
 width: 400px;
}
#content h1 {
 color: #7E7E7E;
 font: bold 25px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: -0.05em;
 line-height: 20px;
 margin: 10px 0 30px;
}
#content h1:before,
#content h1:after {
 content: "";
 height: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 width: 27%;
}
#content h1:after {
 background: rgb(126,126,126);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(left,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    right: 0;
}
#content h1:before {
 background: rgb(126,126,126);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(right,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    left: 0;
}
#content:after,
#content:before {
 background: #f9f9f9;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%, rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f8f8f8', endColorstr='#f9f9f9',GradientType=0 );
 border: 1px solid #c4c6ca;
 content: "";
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 left: -1px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}
#content:after {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(2deg);
 transform: rotate(2deg);
 top: 0;
 z-index: -1;
}
#content:before {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 transform: rotate(-3deg);
 top: 0;
 z-index: -2;
}
#content form { margin: 0 20px; position: relative }
#content form input[type="text"],
#content form input[type="password"] {
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 -ms-border-radius: 3px;
 -o-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
 -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
 -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 background: #eae7e7 url(http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/8bcLQqF.png) no-repeat;
 border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
 color: #777;
 font: 13px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 padding: 15px 10px 15px 40px;
 width: 80%;
}
#content form input[type="text"]:focus,
#content form input[type="password"]:focus {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ed1c24 inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ed1c24 inset;
 -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ed1c24 inset;
 -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ed1c24 inset;
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ed1c24 inset;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ed1c24;
 outline: none;
}
#username { background-position: 10px 10px !important }
#password { background-position: 10px -53px !important }
#content form input[type="submit"] {
 background: rgb(254,231,154);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,231,154,1) 0%, rgba(254,193,81,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,231,154,1) 0%,rgba(254,193,81,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,231,154,1) 0%,rgba(254,193,81,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,231,154,1) 0%,rgba(254,193,81,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,231,154,1) 0%,rgba(254,193,81,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fee79a', endColorstr='#fec151',GradientType=0 );
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 -ms-border-radius: 30px;
 -o-border-radius: 30px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset;
 -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset;
 -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset;
 border: 1px solid #D69E31;
 color: #85592e;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: left;
 font: bold 15px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 height: 35px;
 margin: 20px 0 35px 15px;
 position: relative;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 width: 120px;
}
#content form input[type="submit"]:hover {
 background: rgb(254,193,81);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,193,81,1) 0%, rgba(254,231,154,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,193,81,1) 0%,rgba(254,231,154,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,193,81,1) 0%,rgba(254,231,154,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,193,81,1) 0%,rgba(254,231,154,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,193,81,1) 0%,rgba(254,231,154,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fec151', endColorstr='#fee79a',GradientType=0 );
}
#content form div a {
 color: #004a80;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 30px 15px 0 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.button {
 background: rgb(247,249,250);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,249,250,1) 0%, rgba(240,240,240,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,249,250,1) 0%,rgba(240,240,240,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,249,250,1) 0%,rgba(240,240,240,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,249,250,1) 0%,rgba(240,240,240,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,249,250,1) 0%,rgba(240,240,240,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f7f9fa', endColorstr='#f0f0f0',GradientType=0 );
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
 -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
 -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 -o-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 -ms-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 border-top: 1px solid #CFD5D9;
 padding: 15px 0;
}
.button a {
 background: url(http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/8bcLQqF.png) 0 -112px no-repeat;
 color: #7E7E7E;
 font-size: 17px;
 padding: 2px 0 2px 40px;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.button a:hover {
 background-position: 0 -135px;
 color: #00aeef;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Online Student Service Center</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
  </head>

  <body>

    <body>
<div class="container">
 <section id="content">
  <form action="php/login.php" method="POST" >
   <h1>Login Form</h1>
   <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Student ID" required="" id="username" />
   </div>
   <div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" />
   </div>
   <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    <a href="#">Lost your password?</a>
    <a href="#">Register</a>
   </div>
  </form><!-- form -->
  <div class="button">
   <a href="admin.html">Admin</a>
  </div><!-- button -->
  
 <div class="button">
<a href="teacher.html">Teacher</a>
</div><!-- button -->

 </section><!-- content -->
</div><!-- container -->
</body>

  </body>
</html>
```

please also tell me that how i can fetch data from database

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please remember that SO is for debugging, not a service to write code for you.

Comment: okayhttp://stackoverflow.com/users/6773269/patrick-mlr

Comment: If you want to reply, use `@Patrick Mlr` instead. Not the profile-link.

Answer (score 0):

You just have Css and Html. You can not connect database with this informations. My advice is, try to create your own database and try to connect database on localhost. Y

You must be know database login information. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) is the php database connection lesson.

Comment: please can you send me the php code of login a user

Answer (score 0):

**For Login**

STEPS.>

1.Create Database

2.Connect to the database

3.Gather the posted data into the variables

4.Check the posted variables with database

5.Login Succesful

learn from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysql_login.htm)